# Can I set a Message Delivery Restriction for a mailbox via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The goal is change so that the user mailbox only accepts messages from certain senders?

This can be done using PowerShell or the Exchange web interface. 
Can this be done using [Microsoft Graph API](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/)?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported via Microsoft Graph.

Purely administrative functionality like this is often only accessible via a portal or PowerShell. If you're looking to build a custom front-end for this functionality, you may be able to leverage `System.Management.Automation` and [execute the PowerShell script from C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kebab/2014/04/28/executing-powershell-scripts-from-c/).