# Can I set a Message Delivery Restriction for a group mailbox via Microsoft Graph?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Can I modify the 'Delivery Management > Accept/Decline Messages From...' settings for a Group using MS Graph? I would like to be able to add/remove groups to the allowed senders list, ideally.

This can be done using the Exchange PowerShell library, or the Exchange web interface. Can this be done using Microsoft Graph API?

I know this is a duplicate of this question: [Can I set a Message Delivery Restriction for a mailbox via Microsoft Graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546609/can-i-set-a-message-delivery-restriction-for-a-mailbox-via-microsoft-graph)

But I wanted to ask: is this *still* not supported? Seems like functionality which should be accessible through MsGraph at some point...

Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I think I've answered my own question. Posting here for anyone else who can't find this information elsewhere:

```
$updatePayload = @{
  "@odata.id" =
     "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<USER_EMAIL>"} 
     #This seems to work for groups and distribution lists too, just use their email. 

$response   = Invoke-MgGraphRequest                 
  -Uri 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/<GROUP_ID>/acceptedSenders/$ref'  
  -Method     POST                                
  -Body       $updatePayload                      
  -OutputType HttpResponseMessage
```